# Console App to Services

Tags: c#, service, console-application, topshelf

I'm working on a project who use a Forex API.

So basicaly, what she do:
Loop to check if a new value exist,
if she exist, put it in MongoDB Collection.
if not, keep looping.

My console work just fine but what I need to do is to make it works as Services.

What I've done:

- I've already create my InstallerService and my Service1.cs
- I've used (Environement.UserInterface) in my entry point to make it work as Console App to make the debug painless, and as Service.

When I use installutil.exe, it's complete perfectly and it appear  in my service.msc. I can start it and stop it.

BUT, it seems he don't receive any data, and so, don't put anything in the base. Although it's work perfectly fine as Console App.

So, if anybody have any idea of what it could come from. I would apreciate some help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it when running as a service? Load the project, and then use Tools | Attach To Process (you'll need to run VS as administrator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a console application I would suggest just using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/)

Comment: `ServiceBase` is almost trivially easy to wrap in an interactive console wrapper: why add a project dependency? Do you have some involvement in that project?

Comment: I have no involvement to that project, but debugging and deploying Windows service with c# standard tools is nightmare

Comment: After some hour of seeking why it didn't work. I finally tried TopShelf. 2minutes later. It's was ON.

Comment: I'm sure glad to hear it was all of 2 minutes to get up and running. As one of the developers of Topshelf, this is exactly the goal. Good luck!